# What happens to the signal reception rate if the receiver is moving around in a circle with constant speed?

Tags: special-relativity

A person with a transmitter stand at centre of a circle and another person with receiver rotating in a circular motion with 90% speed of light. If transmitter send messages in all direction ( both transmitter and receiver works perfectly ). If person with transmitter send messages at the rate of 5 messages per second then will the person with receiver will receive message at same rate ? If yes then why time not diluted and if no then why ?? Message signals are electromagnetic waves

Answer (score 0):

The standing person says: "For each second that ticks on the revolving person's watch my watch ticks 2.29 seconds, I send 11.4 messages, and the receiver receives 11.4 messages".

That was straightforward.

The revolving person says: "For each second that I see ticking on the 'standing' - as he calls himself - person's watch, my watch ticks 0.43 seconds, I see the sender sending 5 messages, and I receive 5 messages. So in one my second I receive 11.4 messages".

That was somewhat convoluted. When the person said 'see' he meant seeing, his eyes saw whatever he said he was seeing.

Revolving person also says: "I calculate the 'standing' person's watch to tick one second when my watch ticks 2.29 seconds, I calculate sender sending 2.29 messages per my second, but for some odd reason I am receiving 11.4 messages per my second... Well that's just because the 'standing' person was moving towards me. There is a relativistic Doppler-shift of the stream of messages, because the 'standing' person was moving towards me at great speed".

Now,how does this make sense? Well, let's say the revolving person wrote some of his calculations and observations on a diary. Anyone reading the diary can observe that: "this makes no sense, something is wrong with the mind of the person that wrote this. The mind is kind of ... non-inertial ... changing with time."